# apache tomcat / Intellij idea

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

Could anyone help me please. when I try to Run my java ee application in apache tomcat, the browser show this...[image]

Comment: Is it possible to provide sample project for investigation?

Comment: Please see [ask]. How can we tell you anything from just seeing this? Also please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being the requested URL `http://localhost:8080/controller?action=main`, it is possible that you missed to include the **context name** in the URL, like this:

`http://localhost:8080/context/controller?action=main`

Make sure that your application is not being deployed to the default context, then check what is its name, and write the complete URL in your web browser.

If that is not the cause, make sure also that your application has been well deployed when running Tomcat: Read the console output and check for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I have not written the application context name in my URL(Edit configuration->Deployment->Application context).[image]